# Reload Nifi libraries without restarting Nifi Service

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I need to know if there any way to refresh/reload nifi libraries without re-starting services ?

We have big Nifi Central cluster shared between different countries and any change in cluster affect everyone . It is difficult to afford downtime for any testing.

Does someone has an approach to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is not a way to reload libraries while NiFi is running so you have to restart the instance.

In the future there will likely be a way to automatically load new libraries, meaning if someone adds a new NAR to the lib directory it will get loaded.